# Open subgroup of units of local field (norm index computation)

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-field

Let $k$ be a $\mathfrak{p}$-adic field, $K/k$ be a cyclic extension with Galois group $G = \langle \sigma \rangle$, and $U_K$ be the group of units in (the valuation ring of) $K$.  One of the results of Chapter IX of Lang's *Algebraic Number Theory* is the computation of the Herbrand quotient $Q(G, U_K) := (U_k : N^K_kU_K)/(\ker N^K_k : (1-\sigma)U_K)$ where $\ker N^K_k$ is the kernel of the norm as a homomorphism from $U_K$ to $U_k$. Knowing the value of this quotient is useful, e.g. in computing the index $(k^* : N^K_kK^*) = [K:k]$.

The trick Lang uses is as follows (from p. 188):

> Let $\{\omega_\tau\}$ be a normal basis for $K$ over $k$. After multiplying the elements of this basis by a high power of a prime element $\pi$ in $k$, we can assume that they have small absolute value. Let $M = \sum_{\tau \in G} \mathcal{O}_k\cdot \omega_\tau$.

As far as I can tell, the reason for this first step is to ensure that the exponential map is well-defined on $M$, since the power series defining it only converges on sufficiently small neighborhoods of $0$.

> The $G$ acts on $M$ semilocally, with trivial decomposition group. Furthermore, $\exp M = V$ is $G$-isomorphic to $M$ (the inverse is given by the log), and $V$ is an open subgroup of the units, whence of finite index in $U_K$. Therefore $1 = Q(G, V) = Q(G, U_K)$.

It's clear to me why this implies that $V$ has finite index ($U_K$ is compact).  However, I don't understand exactly why $V$ is open in $U_K$. Should this be obvious? Also, why does this depend on  $G$ being cyclic?

Comment: $\exp(x) = 1+x+O(x^2)$ this guanrantees for $n$ large enough $\exp(1+\pi^n O_K) = 1+\pi^n O_K$ which is finite index open subgroup of $U_K = \langle \zeta\rangle (1+\pi O_K)$.  What does it mean G  acts on M semilocally, with trivial decomposition group ? Can you elaborate on $Q(G,V)$ and $1 = Q(G, V) = Q(G, U_K)$ ? Also finite index implies open.

Comment: @reuns: Oops, in the question I meant that it was clear why the index is finite from the fact that it is open, but that I wasn't sure about why it is open in the first place (the fact that it is open is the only part I don't know how to prove; the rest of the question is just providing details). Also, did you mean to write $\exp(\pi^n\mathcal{O}_K) = 1 + \pi^n\mathcal{O}_K$?

Comment: Yes. So can you elaborate on those $Q(G,U_K)$ and what are they useful for (the proof of the surjectivity of $\exp(\pi^n\mathcal{O}_K) \to 1 + \pi^n\mathcal{O}_K$ is the same as in Hensel lemma : fix the p-adic digits of the LHS one by ones to fit the RHS)

Comment: Okay! I provided more details on the Herbrand quotient in the question. The fact that exp is a $G$-isomorphism between a small neighborhood of $0$ and a small neighborhood of $1$ in this case has already been proved by the construction of the log map (I'd be curious to know if there's any way in which your proof and the proof via the log map are directly equivalent). However, I don't understand why $V = \exp(M)$ is open. Is $M$ an open subset of $K$?

Comment: I think it's obvious. Prove for yourself: If $K\vert k$ is a finite extension of local fields, $\mathcal{O}_k$ the ring of integers of $k$, and $e_1, ..., e_n$ any vector space basis of $K$ over $k$, the lattice ($\mathcal{O}_k$-module) $\sum_1^n \mathcal{O}_k \cdot e_i$ is open.

Comment: Oh, I see now: $\sum_{1}^n \mathcal{O}_k\cdot e_i$ is a discrete subgroup of $K$, and hence a closed subgroup (since $K$ is Hausdorff). It is also of finite index in $\mathcal{O}_K$ (both are free $\mathcal{O}k$-modules of rank $n$; the index is finite for example by the proof of the structure theorem for modules over a PID). Finally, it's a general fact that a closed subgroup of finite index (in an arbitrary topological group) is open, so $M$ is open in $\mathcal{O}_K$ and therefore in $K$ (as $\mathcal{O}_K$ is open in $K$). Is this the proof you had in mind?

Comment: No, I don't think that lattice is discrete, and also, for general $e_i$, it's not contained in $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: Oops, you are right; I am very bad. Actually $K$ is a finite-dimensional normed vector space over $k$, and since $k$ is complete the norm on $K$ is equivalent to the sup norm with respect to the basis $\{e_i\}$. From that it's obvious that $M$ is open (it's just an open cube under the sup norm).